# Outer apply on another outer apply?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, outer-join

I have a problem with an SQL request I am working on.

I would like to return the **total** number of a certain item that is ordered by a certain customer. The problem is: I get more than one line when I execute my request.

(*Please note that this is a **very simplified** version of my request to help the comprehension of the code. My tables are **not** named like this, neither are my rows.*)

```
SELECT outerpallet.pallet as palletnbr, ID, shipmentID FROM arandomtable
OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM(palletnbr) as pallet FROM thepallettable GROUP BY arandomtable.ID) as outerpallet
WHERE ID = @something
```

What I get:

```
palletnbr  ID    shipmentid
1          2     340
2          3     340
3          4     340
```

What I would like to get (whitout necessarily having the ID and shipmentid):

```
palletnbr
6
```

To do this I would have to get all my lines in one. I thought of doing another outer apply, but it won't work (since I am doing an outer apply of another outer apply)...

I thought of maybe doing my outer apply in another way, but I can't seem to find out how. I tried to add:

```
GROUP BY shipmentid
```

But it would have to be in the OUTER APPLY, and I can't seem to figure out how to put it there.

Would anyone have an idea that could help me to solve this problem ? Any little hint would be of a great help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I have gotten to do what I wanted to do, following a little the answer of Gordon.
Here is the code I went with, if it can ever be of interest to someone that would have the same question I had:

```
SELECT outerpallet.pallet as palletnbr, ID, shipmentID FROM arandomtable
--(here are all of my other join that do not affect the question)
OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM(palletnbr) as pallet 
FROM thepallettable 
INNER JOIN shipmenttable ON shipmenttable.shipmentid = thepallettable.shipmentid
INNER JOIN shipmentdetail ON shipmenttable.shipmentid = shipmentable.shipmentdtlid
GROUP BY shipmentdetail.ID) as outerpallet
WHERE ID = @something
```

*This is a very shortened and basic version*, but it might help someone that is stuck. I basically put some other `INNER JOIN` on my `OUTER APPLY`, so it helped me get more precision. Surely this is not the most effective way to do so, but this was ok in my case since it was used in a small part of the project, and thus would not be solicited by more than one customer (this was a client personalisation of our main program).

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

I realize that your query might be more complicated.  The version in your question seems more easily answers with a `join` than with `cross apply`:

```
SELECT SUM(palletnbr) as palletnbr, arandomtable.ID, arandomtable.shipmentID
FROM arandomtable left outer join
     thepallettable 
     on thepallettable.randomID = arandomtable.ID
WHERE arandomtable.ID = @something
group by arandomtable.ID, arandomtable.shipmentID;
```

Is there a reason you need `cross apply`?

Comment: My querry would look more like somthing like this:
SELECT (...) FROM arandomtable
INNER JOIN x on y = z
INNER JOIN x on y = z
INNER JOIN x on y = z
INNER JOIN x on y = z
INNER JOIN x on y = z
LEFT JOIN x ON y = z
LEFT JOIN z on y = z
OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM(palletnbr) as pallet FROM thepallettable GROUP BY arandomtable.ID) as outerpallet
WHERE (condition)

Comment: So the outer apply would be the only way that I've seen to get what I want.